# Paypal NVP API using certificate instead of signature

Tags: paypal, builder

Is anybody familiar with the following pattern of authenticating with the signature ?

```
Profile user = new BaseProfile.Builder("name", "password").signature("AfcWX...").build();
```

Instead of the signature, can we authenticate with a certificate (PKCS12) instead ?

Should i give a path to it or the actual certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you have to provide the path to your certificate. I use PHP with CURL and I have to tell it where the file lives. Some systems might take it as a string, tho.

You get the certificate from Paypal when you request API credentials.